# Bash script to recursively add a file to multiple directories

Tags: bash, directory, copy

I have a bunch of directory's in /home/servers2 (like a few thousand) and in each directory in server2 there is a directory called plugins Ex. /home/servers2/MyServer/plugins

In each one right now there is a file called AutoStopFinal.jar, I need to remove that, and then copy over AutoStop1.3.001 to the plugins directory from /home/servers/template/plugins.
I wanted to non destuctivly test it so I tried this:

```
echo " Script to copy a plugin to all server plugin directories"

for i in /home/servers2/*/plugins; do
    echo rm -f $i/AutoStopFinal.jar
    echo cp -f /home/servers/template/plugins/AutoStop1.3.001.jar "$i"
done

echo " completed script ..."
```

But only got Script to copy a plugin to all server plugin directories. I Controled C'd out of it after about 5 minutes. But I got no echos from inside the loop, any advice?

Comment: no output means not even " Script to copy a plugin to all server plugin directories" and  " completed script ..."

Comment: My mistake, it did give the Script to copy a plugin to all plugin directories

Comment: maybe the path expansion doesn't match

Comment: If there are really a few thousand directories under /home/servers, you will likely have too many to fit on one command line. You'll have to use the `find` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use find to do this for you like this:

```
cd /home/servers2
find . -type d -name plugins -exec cp -f /home/servers/template/plugins/AutoStop1.3.001.jar {} \; -exec rm -f {}/AutoStopFinal.jar \;
```

Answer (score 1):

This command will remove the files:

```
find ./servers2 -name AutoStopFinal.jar |xargs -n1 rm
```

This command will copy the new file into place:

```
find ./servers2 -name plugins |xargs -n1 cp ./servers/template/plugins/AutoStop1.3.001.jar
```